# xls saved using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser saveas fails to open using MSExcel

Tags: perl, excel

I have an issue with the excel sheet created using  Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser saveas function doesn't open using MSExcel.

code snippet:

```
    my $result_excel="result.xls";
    my $excel_template="Template.xls";

    my $parser   = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
    my $template = $parser->Parse($excel_template);

    my $workbook;
    {
        local $^W = 0;

        $workbook = $parser->SaveAs($template, $result_excel);
    }
    $workbook->close();
```

The xls created by running this script on my machine is perfectly fine. But any other machine I try to run it on, I am seeing that the xls doesn't open but throws an error saying "Excel found unreadable content in result.xls....". 
working machine:
win 7
perl v5.8.7 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
excel 2010 with vba

non working machines:

1. win7, perl v 5.6.1, excel 2010 without vba
2. win7, perl v 5.8.7, excel 2010 without vba
3. win7, perl v 5.8.7, excel 2010 with vba
4. win7, perl v 5.6.1, excel 2010 with vba

(vba is visual basic component in Office 2010)

I am unable to figure out if it is a perl issue or a excel issue. Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Why you set local `$^W` to zero? Do you suppress some warnings there?

Comment: yes, I was seeing too many warnings.

Comment: Even without setting $^W to zero, the behavior is same. I am blocked on this. can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe those warnings have some useful information in?